# I keep getting and heroku master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error

Tags: python, git, heroku

this is the error, I tried to force push as suggested on another page but unfortunatly  it didn't work. when using git status it also says that that .DS_store file is modified (which as far as I know is a secret macOS file.

```
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 9124da0df6637b15c4ade2f515a79c463ea52ed0
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 9124da0df6637b15c4ade2f515a79c463ea52ed0
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to nartonmusic.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/nartonmusic.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nartonmusic.git'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+%5Bpython%5D+remote%3A+-----%3E+App+not+compatible+with+buildpack